# passing value using viewmodel is empty

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I have this viewmodel:

```
public class AmountViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<String> amount = new MutableLiveData<String>();

    public void setAmount(long value) {
        amount.postValue(Long.toString(value));
    }

    public LiveData<String> getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

I am using it to pass the amount from a fragment to an activity:

AFragment:

```
amountViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AmountViewModel.class);
amountViewModel.setAmount(1000);
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Then I databinding the amunt value in NextActivity, but the data I get is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewModel` objects are tied to the `Lifecycle` passed to the `ViewModelProvider`. When you first create your `ViewModel`  in the fragment:

```
amountViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AmountViewModel.class);
```

it becomes scoped to that fragment's lifecycle. It means that when you start the new activity and try to retrieve the `ViewModel` there, a new one will be created which will be bound to the activity's lifecycle.

If you want to share `ViewModel` between screens you should probably use a single `Activity` and switch between different `Fragments` which can all use the same `ViewModel` scoped to that activity's lifecycle. I suggest trying out [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) which simplifies navigation using fragments.

Otherwise, if you want to stick to your current implementation and persist data between activities you should use options such as `SharedPreferences`, files or others, depending on the type of data you want to store.